# Using C, in linux(raspberry pi) how to scan advertising packet with socket function

Tags: c

I want to scan advertising packet in raspberry pi using C socket.
so I installed libbluetooth-dev
(I have bluetooth.h, bnep.h, cmtp.h, hci.h, hci_lib.h, hidp.h, l2cap.h, rfcomm.h, sco.h, sdp.h,sdp_lib.h)
I don't need connect, pairing, data transfer function...etc..
I need to extract MAC-address from advertising packet only

1. accept() function is necessary?
2. which header included